# My c-function using difftime returns 65535 sometimes

Tags: c

I have a function that uses difftime to detect the time in seconds since the communication heartbeat has stopped.  This function could run as fast as every 50 milliseconds.  The function seems to work except once in a while it returns 65535.  I can reduce the execution to once a second since the return of difftime is only in seconds.  But I don't know if it will fix the problem.  Is it the problem because I am not properly casting the difftime return back to uint16_t from double?

This program runs in an ubuntu 64bit machine.

Please help.  Thanks.

```
uint16_t commlost(uint16_t heartbeat_read_cur)
{  
    time_t current_time;  
    static time_t previous_time;  
    static uint16_t commlost_secs_cur = 0;  
    static uint16_t commlost_secs_prev = 0;  
    static uint16_t heartbeat_read_prev = 0;  
    static bool first_time = TRUE;
    if (first_time)
    {
        previous_time = time(NULL);
        first_time = FALSE;
    }

    time(&current_time);

    commlost_secs_prev = commlost_secs_cur;

    if(heartbeat_read_prev == heartbeat_read_cur)
    {

        commlost_secs_cur += difftime(current_time, previous_time);
    }
    else
    {
        heartbeat_read_prev = heartbeat_read_cur;
        commlost_secs_cur = 0;
    }

    previous_time = current_time;

    return (commlost_secs_cur);
}
```

Comment: It is an odd number... maybe is it returning -1 (that assumes that the return type is a 16 bits integer, not a 32 bits integer)? I would check the documentation of the function.

Comment: `difftime()` returns `double`.  Maybe the `double` --> `uint16_t` is overflowing?

Comment: Look at the values of `current_time` and `previous_time`, and the result returned by `difftime()`, either by using a debugger or by adding `printf` calls, whichever you find more convenient. 65535 seconds is 18+ hours; it's also the maximum value of a `uint16)t`.

Comment: @chux: An overflow is plausible, but I find (on a similar system) that it wraps around rather than saturating at 65535.

Comment: Are you perhaps calling this function from more than one thread?

Comment: No, only called from one thread.  Thanks.

Comment: Suspect when `commlost_secs_cur == 65535` that `current_time == previous_time - 1`.  This _could_ happen for a number of unusual reasons like system clock adjustment - but I do not know why it happens here.  It just smells like time ticked backwards 1 step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difftime()` is of use on systems where `time_t` supports time to a higher resolution than integral seconds.  Although allowed, I've never encountered such a system - I don't imagine one exists.  On POSIX systems specifically, `time_t` is measured in integral seconds, and `difftime()` is equivalent to arithmetic subtraction of its arguments, so in fact you are better off simply using:

```
commlost_secs_cur += current_time - previous_time ;
```

That said, your implementation is somewhat over-complex, rather than accumulating time since the previous call, which may be smaller than the clock resolution, you could simply time-stamp the last heartbeat observed and return time since then:

```
int commlost(uint16_t heartbeat_read_cur)
{  
    time_t current_time = time(0) ;  
    static time_t heartbeat_timestamp = 0 ; 
    static uint16_t heartbeat_read_prev  ;

    // If first time, or heartbeat changed...
    if( heartbeat_timestamp == 0 || heartbeat_read_prev != heartbeat_read_cur)
    {
        // ... timestamp heartbeat
        heartbeat_timestamp = time(0) ;

        // ... keep last heartbeat
        heartbeat_read_prev = heartbeat_read_cur ;
    }

    // Return seconds since last heartbeat timestamp
    return current_time - heartbeat_timestamp ;
}
```

I am not sure why you would use `uint16_t` for this; there is little or no advantage unless it is for compatibility with some specific protocol or file format.

Comment: Note: Even is `time_t` is not in seconds, the results of `difftime()` is in seconds.

Comment: @chux : Yes, but it is needlessly a `double`.  The question asked whether the problem might be in the conversion from `double`;  I doubt it, but this solution avoids the conversion altogether so will easily discount that hypothesis.  As am embedded systems developer, targeting platforms that seldom support an FPU and have limited memory resources, I habitually avoid floating-point where possible, and here it is possible.

Comment: I agree     uint16_t    is not a good choice.  The existing program I am working with uses it for similar variables.  I wanted to keep things in the same format and didn't think it would be an issue.  I like your simplified code using time stamp.  Basile's suggestion is good too but this is closer to what I need for this application.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3569894 : maintaining type agreement is a reasonable argument for using a different type.  in which case `return (uint16_t)(current_time - heartbeat_timestamp)` - the conversion is otherwise implicit and may generate warnings or fail separate static analysis.

Comment: Note that using difftime() is still valid and provides strict portability, but it would be a brave library designer who would decide to implement time_t differently to the *defacto* norm.  I really do not know why your original code failed (so have not really answered the question), but if simplifying it also solves the problem - all's well I suppose?

Answer (score 3):

Before querying time, read the [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) man page (and read it again).

The, I suggest using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with e.g. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` or `CLOCK_REALTIME`, and preferably use `double` for time calculations (since a `struct timespec` is generally larger than any integral type).

Don't use `uint16_t` for such time calculations.

Try using

```
inline double double_gettime (clockid_t cid) {
  struct timespec ts = {0,0};
  clock_gettime(cid, &ts);
  return (double)ts.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*ts.tv_nsec;
}
```

<sup>You might want to make that function fancier, by testing if `clock_gettime` is failing and giving `NAN` when it fails! This is left as an exercise to the reader. You could also, for `CLOCK_REALTIME` etc, measure the *difference* between some time at start of process and the current time (i.e. compute a `struct timespec` of differences and convert that difference to a `double`)</sup>

Then things like

```
double tstart = double_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME);
some_long_computation();
double tend = double_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME);
printf ("needed %f seconds to compute\n", tend-tstart);
```

See also [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html)

Comment: Thank you, This is very nice.  Will definitely have good use for it.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: What is the reasoning to use double for calculations when it can be done using long long too?