# Calculating the total time for which program ran in c

Tags: c, linux

I have a program in c which runs forever until I press CTRL+C. After the termination I need to show the total time for which the program ran. What to do so as to find the total time for which the program ran?
if there is a code for it then please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Simly record timestamp on startup and on exit. Then make a diff.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to compute this *inside* your program or outside it (using `time(1)`).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a program called `time`.

Run

```
time ./program
```

Comment: But the OP want to do that inside his program.

Comment: I understand that but it might be a more pragmatical solution for him or her than handling term signal. Let him or her pick up the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [times(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html) (or [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`), or simply [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html), to get the processor time (inside your program in C).

If you need the real elapsed time, record the start time using [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) or preferably [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) and compute the difference at end. You might want to get a `double` measurement of time using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23278519/841108) to convert what `clock_gettime` gives you (a `struct timespec`) into a `double`.

Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) (and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) if you want to catch <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, see also [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html)). Perhaps using [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) -as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074859/841108) by Grzegorz Żur- should be enough.

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Comment: For code interrupted with Ctrl+C one should also add signal handling (e.g. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/ ).

Comment: Yes, but I guess the OP is handling `SIGINT`