# How to calculate the % of CPU used by the threads in a process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process

I am working with an opencv application,The main process uses 3 threads .
I want to know the % of CPU consumed by each threads in the process?

Comment: One of best questions in a while

Comment: Yeah, and there is still no satisfactory answer I can find that does NOT suggest to parse data from /proc ...

Answer (score 2):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) then [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), notably with `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`  and `CLOCK_REALTIME`. You probably want to compute the *variation* of these clocks (from e.g. the start of the thread) and the ratio of their variations. You probably want to convert the result of `clock_gettime` (or their delta) into a `double` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23278519/841108)), since a `struct timespec` is often larger than a `long long` or any integral type on your machine. See also [pthread_getcpuclockid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html).

Notice that a thread can be migrated by the kernel [scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) from one core to another one. See however [sched_setaffinity(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) used by [pthread_setaffinity_np(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html).

See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). You might be tempted to parse `/proc/self/stat` and `/proc/self/status` etc...

Look also into [times(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html) & [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) & [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and possibly dirty (but meaningful) estimate at the process level I get the user+system time (from getrusage()) plus the actual real time elapsed, then divide the latter by the former.

Sadly I haven't been able to figure out how to do this at the thread level and that's exactly how I came across this question.
There is `getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD,...)` and `clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,..)` on Linux but I'm getting strange results when I use the results from those functions as outlined above. The estimate does approach 100% CPU for threads that ought all be busy doing simple things (like reading 1-file-per-thread contents into 2 buffers then comparing them). However, this does not depend on the number of threads I spawn so I can get 8*100%CPU on a machine with 4 cores which shouldn't be possible. Indeed, top and the shell's time command show I'm far from full CPU load, more at about 250% on average (for that 8 threads on a 4-core machine example).

If I were to guess I'd say that the per-and-in thread measurement functions only measure actual time spent running the thread, excluding most if not all overhead like context switches. That should apply at least to the result returned by CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID (including thread overhead in getrusage's system time estimate seems justifiable).